# Object has no method 'placeholder'

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-9, placeholder

I am using [mathiasbynens / jquery-placeholder](http://mths.be/placeholder) to enable placeholders in IE9. I followed the simple steps mentioned in the read me.

But I get **Object [object Object] has no method 'placeholder'** in the console at the line `$('input, textarea').placeholder();`

Any Idea what is the problem ??

Comment: Works perfectly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/euQ4v/ Could you provide more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like jquery-placeholder isn't being included in the page properly. Check you have the right url in your script tag and that the script is being included before you call the `placeholder()` method.

Comment: I made sure I have the right url. if it was wrong I would have found it mentioned in the console. And the script is included b4 the mentioning

Comment: Can you post a bigger code sample please. The error you're getting is exactly as if the placeholder plugin isn't being included... Also, come to think of it, which jquery version are you using? the `bind` method has been removed from v1.9 and placeholder plugin relies on it

Comment: Find the solution, it seems I didn't have the perfect order. I had to import the script after the bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the attribute the regular, crafty way:

```
$('input, textarea').attr('placeholder', 'value');
```

Comment: IE9 doesn't support placeholders, which is why the questioner is using the plugin.